# how to create input submit interface in telegram bot (in Facebook bot available)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

[image]
I am new to Telegram chatbot development. I want to create input interface for Telegram bot like I've given the image above. The above bot in created in Facebook Messanger bot. But I Want to create it in Telegram.
Is there any way to do like that, in Telegram?
or Any other custom way to use along with Telegram?
Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in Telegram. Why not ask the user to just type it in the chat?

Comment: ** But, I must get the user input from input field (For Security Reason) . Is any other third party service for doing so?. ** . I need that type of interface when i click on the inline button.

Comment: could i solve this problem using TDLib provided by Telegram? What is the use of TDLib?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?